# Laravel - Posting Data to multiple tables with a single form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Let's say I have this form (linked to a named route) that contains 3 text inputs :

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'domain.store'])!!}
{!!  Form::text('srv_prefix',null, $attributes = array('class' => 'form-control input-md')) !!}
{!!  Form::text('srv_ip',null, $attributes = array('class' => 'form-control input-md')) !!}
{!!  Form::text('domain',null, $attributes = array('class' => 'form-control input-md')) !!}
{!!  Form::submit('create') !!}
```

the route calls this function on my controller:

```
public function store(CreateDomainRequest $request, Domain $domain)
{
    $domain->create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('domain.index');
}
```

Always as example, let's say I have 2 tables : `domains` to store my domains, and `servers` to store my servers info (1st and second text input) actually I managed to do the inserts on my first table using the controller mentioned above. my question is how can I do the inserts on the 2 tables via a single submit on my form? how to deal with a Request and a controller for each table ?

this is what i did so far :

1 - i have already have 2 related models (`Server`and `Domain`):

```
Class Server extends Eloquent {
    public function domain(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Domain');
    }
// $fillable and stuff..
}
```

-

```
Class Domain extends Eloquent {
    public function servers(){
    return $this->hasMany('Server');
    }
//
}
```

2 - I'm using eloquent, and my tables are related.

```
    Schema::table('servers', function($table){
        $table->foreign('id_domain')
            ->references('id_dom')
            ->on('domains')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

The [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models) does not show how to insert related models using a form. thanks for your help :)

Comment: What I do is create a command/job which stores everything in a particular request, I need accordingly and dispatch the command/job from my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would handle this.  I'm assuming `srv_prefix` and `srv_ip` both are attributes of `Server`.

```
public function store(CreateDomainRequest $request, Domain $domain, Server $server)
{
    // Since domain is the parent, we need to start there.
    $domain = $domain->create($request->all());

    // Now you can create the server model
    $server->fill([
        'prefix' => \Input::get('srv_prefix'),
        'ip' => \Input::get('srv_ip')
    ]);

    // Now we can attach the server to the domain
    $domain->servers()->save($server);

    return redirect()->route('domain.index');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. that seems to be the right approach. but since I have a FK on my `servers` table (whice is the `id` of the `domain`table) I keep getting this error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'domain_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into 'servers' ('domain_id', 'updated_at', 'created_at') values (, 2015-11-25 10:55:45, 2015-11-25 10:55:45))` my store function looks like : 
        `$vip->create($request->all());
        $pool->vip()->associate($vip);
        $pool->save();
        $pool->create($request->only(['srv_hostname','srv_ip','srv_port']));`

Comment: Oops, I think you should use `fill` rather than `create` on the `Server` model.  This way it doesn't actually save until you know what the `domain_id` is going to be.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: I dont think the problem is with `create` : I commented the whole line, All I have now is `$domain->create($request->all());$server->domain()->associate($domain);$server->save();` yet Laravel manages to generate the right query, but the FK is missing

Comment: marked your answer as the right one. and started a new one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33916181/laravel-inserting-foreign-keys-causes-integrity-constraint-violation/ since this is a different problem.