# Laravel - inserting foreign keys causes Integrity constraint violation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have two related models `Domain`and `Server`. I'm trying to insert data to my tables using a form. here is my store function :

```
public function store(Request $request, Domain $domain, Server $server)
{
    $domain->create($request->all());

    $server->domain()->associate($domain);
    $server->save();
    $server->create($request->only(['srv_hostname','srv_ip','srv_port']));

    return redirect()->route('domains.index');
}
```

the table `servers` has a FK `domain_id` that points to the PK `domain.id`
Once I submit my form i get the error :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'domain_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `servers` (`domain_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 2015-11-25 10:55:45, 2015-11-25 10:55:45))

It seems like fk is not correctly linked to the pk..but I don't know how to solve this. thanks :)

**Notes :**

1 - My 2 related models:

```
Class Server extends Eloquent {
    public function domain(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Domain');
   }
// $fillable and stuff..
}
```

-

```
Class Domain extends Eloquent {
    public function servers(){
    return $this->hasMany('Server');
}
//
}
```

2 - My tables are related:

```
Schema::table('servers', function($table){
    $table->foreign('domain_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('domains')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
  $new_domain = $domain->create($request->all());

  $server->domain()->associate($new_domain);
  $server->save();
```

Comment: that solved the problem,The line `$server->fill($request->only(['srv_hostname','srv_ip','srv_port']));` should be kept though. otherwise the `save` function only stores the foreign key and the timestamps.